# ECL Decimal Casting

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I'd like to ask the reason why this is happening.

When I was casting a result to DECIMAL5_2 when using COUNT, it works as planned when the COUNT is in a separate line from the casting:

```
c1 = COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980);
c2 = COUNT(MenBornBefore1980);
PercOlderMalesInMStates := (DECIMAL5_2)(c1/c2 * 100); //result 14.46
```

And when I try to condense it to a one-liner, the output changes:

```
PercOlderMalesInMStates := (DECIMAL5_2)(COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980)/COUNT(MenBornBefore1980) * 100); 
//result is 15
```

But the one liner will work *if* I declare the value to be of the DECIMAL5_2 type:

```
DECIMAL5_2 PercOlderMalesInMStates := (COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980)/COUNT(MenBornBefore1980) * 100); 
//result is 14.86
```

Thank you very much!

---

**EDIT:**
There's a difference between the code I posted above and the one in the actual ECL file in my PC. Apparently, I typed a working expression here while I fumbled the bag in my local ECL file.

One-Liner in this post:

```
PercOlderMalesInMStates := (DECIMAL5_2)(COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980)/COUNT(MenBornBefore1980) * 100); 
//result is indeed correct (14.86)
```

One-Liner in my local ECL file:

```
PercOlderMalesInMStates := (DECIMAL5_2) (COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980)) / COUNT(MenBornBefore1980)) * 100;
//result is incorrect(15)
```

Notice the difference in the parentheses! My guess now as to why this is happening would be that in my local ECL file, the DECIMAL5_2 casting happens before the fraction part can be multiplied by 100, thus it becomes an INTEGER.

Thank you again and sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, this code produces exactly the same (correct) answer for all three:

```
IMPORT $;
IsBornBefore1980 := $.Persons.BirthDate < '1980'; 
MenBornBefore1980 := $.Persons(Gender = 'M',BirthDate < '1980'); 
c1 := COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980));
c2 := COUNT(MenBornBefore1980);
PercOlderMalesInMStates1 := (DECIMAL5_2)(c1/c2 * 100); //result 14.46
PercOlderMalesInMStates2 := (DECIMAL5_2)(COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980))/COUNT(MenBornBefore1980) * 100); 
DECIMAL5_2 PercOlderMalesInMStates3 := COUNT($.MenInMStatesPersons(IsBornBefore1980))/COUNT(MenBornBefore1980) * 100; 
PercOlderMalesInMStates1;
PercOlderMalesInMStates2;
PercOlderMalesInMStates3;
```

I'm not sure why your code produces different results, but I did have to correct several syntax errors before my version of your code would run. Try my version and see what you get.

HTH,

Richard

Comment: Thank you for helping, I'll try to see if I get the same error on a different machine, but I really appreciate your help! I'd also like to clarify that in production-level code, it will be better if I use the "c1,c2" approach since it'll probably be easier to read, right?

Comment: Yes, the "c1,c2" approach creates more readable code and provides the opportunity for reuse of those definitions, if you need them in any other expressions. I would expect that all three versions would end up with essentially the same generated C++ code from the compiler.

Comment: Hi! After careful examination of my code, it seems that the reason why the one-liner doesn't work for me is that my parentheses in the actual code are wrong. The ones in the question work but the one in my code doesn't. It's formatted like:
variable := (DECIMAL5_2) (COUNT(C1) / COUNT(C2)) * 100; 

It's a bit of a rookie mistake on my part to overlook the parentheses. Thank you for helping and sorry for wasting a bit of time!